# How do you share AWS Lambda functions of S3 Buckets to your teams, so they can edit add etc

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am working on an Alexa Skill and I want to share with my teams the Alexa console together with its source code in Lambda and also an S3 bucket. How do I do that on AWS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using Group & policy**

1. Create Group -> Attach policy (AWSS3, Lambda, Alexa)
2. Create user and assign the created group #1

You can refer AWS docs for starter guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/getting-started_create-admin-group.html?shortFooter=true

**For Alexa Console**,

1. Login to Alexa console -> Click on user icon -> select Settings.
2. It will redirect you to https://developer.amazon.com
3. Click on user permission -> Add new user -> select role and invitation will sent to respected user

Refer: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/app-submission/manage-account-and-permissions.html

Comment: Nice! Thanks! Although, how about sharing the Amazon Developer Console for Alexa?

Comment: For Alexa Console, Login to Alexa console -> Click on user icon -> select Settings.
It will redirect you to https://developer.amazon.com
Click on user permission -> Add new user -> select role and invitation will sent to respected user


Refer: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/app-submission/manage-account-and-permissions.html

Answer (score 1):

You can create new user and assign policy from I&AM section as you want.

I&AM > USER > GROUP > Attach policy

For alexa console you can give access to user to edit your skill from developer console (amazon developer).

Add user as a contributor so he can edit skill from his console only